# Possible to put a subdomain on a different server than the domain?

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain

My friend has a website website.com.
It's not on a powerful server. 
She wants to put a shop on the website, e.g. store.website.com

I believe a solution is to put her shop on my own powerful server.

So, is it possible to keep www.website.com on her server, and put store.website.com on my server?

Comment: Yes, it is; that's what the DNS is for.

Comment: Yes I thought so, but I'm not sure how to do this. Can you give an example of what the DNS record should be for both servers?

Comment: Look at the DNS for `www.teaparty.net`, `ntp.teaparty.net` and `nagios.teaparty.net` to see an example.  Basically, each record should point to the IP address for that server.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, It's possible.

For Example.

website.com Has an "A" record pointing to 197.242.76.216
sub.website.com has an "A" record pointing to 87.34.55.32

You would either Contact your Host to set this, or if you have the ability to point
DNS your self then do so. Just make sure that the site you want to serve on that subdomain
exists on the server that it's pointing to.

Comment: Thank you. So server1 is configured to have website.com on it. Server2 is configured to have sub.website.com. The host for website.com updates the DNS record for website.com so it has an A entry for sub.website.com at server2's IP. The host of server2 doesn't need to do any DNS related stuff. Is my understanding correct? Or does host for server2 need to do some DNS stuff for the sub domain? Thank you.

Comment: You are correct. However the servers them selves wont be working with DNS really, IT's just the headers that will detect which website you would like to access. It's the DNS Servers that will be handling the Directions and such.